# Break this regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry for the somewhat truthful misleading title.
I am currently trying to grasp several formats of dates, within a given sentence, will add more as time permits and neccessity arises, but for the most part this is what I have.
https://regex101.com/r/vV0uZ3/1

The main reason why I said break this, is because I can't think of any other types of dates that could mess this up, but I also feel that it is inefficient, semi new to regexes, and this seems to work, but I feel that there is a better manner in which to do it as well, this is somewhat time insensitive data processing, but speed is always a needed point in the end game.

Shortened scope, are there (base) formats of date inputs that this would not be able to pull in?
Also would it be better to use the case insensitive flag 'i' or pull in the full (base) alphabet into it [A-z], for time, and solution comprehension?

EDIT~~
I may be misrepresenting my question a bit, here goes.

I more or less will be reading in human inputs, and mostly american date formats within a document.
I have seen the comments made, and they are definitely sensible, just not too sure if at the moment those edge cases would be plausible, human randomness is a beautiful thing though, so side question, would having a regex that could catch all of these date formats(n/m/e | n-m-e | n m, e |...) heavily bog down my code in the long ru, and would the trade off for maleability be worth the slight shift in efficiency?

Comment: `5-May-2010` appears to break the regex, but more important is that I think you might get better mileage checking the date in JavaScript, possibly using a library if it exists.

Comment: This is roughly my second day dealing with JS, coming from months of heavy Python scripting, that which you specified is one of the cases that I want to add at the end of it all. I'm not too sure I'll be able to use JS's date object/library? for the functional points that I am trying to do, but I will look into it's existence once I have a bit more traction in the language.  The case you highlighted and 5/9/1990 would also break it, but I feel as if checking for soo many cases would break this regex, or severely slow it down if called 1M times or so over the course of 5 minutes.

Comment: Also not working, ISO format: 2016-01-04

Comment: I will edit this post, I feel as if not many people would place dates in these formats.

Comment: As for libraries, I would suggest: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Also not working: 6/17/1999

Comment: Slightly looked into the moments point, It may fit in with what is needed, and  could work, not too sure of it all though, or how I could apply it to he program, will again look back into it when more familiar with the language.